# how to make first element in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a task to make name of user first of all list. Heres the example

```
$scope.items = [John,Bob,Tanya,Owen,George];
```

---

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"></div>
```

The result will be:

```
John
Bob
Tanya
Owen
George
```

How can i make that Owen will be first like:

```
Owen
John
Bob
Tanya
George
```

Comment: Can't you just change your array ($scope.items) to [Owen, John,Bob,Tanya,George]?

Comment: What would determine that `order` ?

Comment: no, i have a list of name from server

Comment: If only Owen have to be the first do this :

var index = $scope.items.indexOf('Owen');
$scope.items.splice(index, 1);
$scope.items.push('Owen');

Comment: Sorry splicing is a good thing but i forget to mention that i use orderBy alphabet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `orderBy`, with an *expression*.

If you had a `JSON` object similar to this one....

```
  $scope.itemsWithOrder = [{
    "name": "Owen",
    "order": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Dave",
    "order": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Ken",
    "order": 2
  }, {
    "name": "John",
    "order": 4
  }];
```

You could then use the `order` property to sort the collection.

```
<div ng-repeat="itemw in itemsWithOrder | orderBy :'order'">
  {{itemw.name}} - {{itemw.order}}
</div>
```

This would give you the output...(you can also reverse the output with a `-`, giving `orderBy :'-order'`)

> Owen - 1
>
> Ken - 2
>
> Dave - 3
>
> John - 4

I know this doesn't help with the object you have, but you may be able to get an alternative object from the server?

Comment: theres the problem, the names come without any destinction to detect the name what i need, and i already use order to sort them by alphabet

Comment: You could *hardcode* the name in, but that would be messy.  I think you're better off sorting alphabetically, or build an array of objects, based on the collection you have, giving *Owen* the `Order` of 1 ***if exists***, otherwise, give the first person in the list 1?

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamjld/85bnhst6/4/)

You can take a look at the fiddle I have provided above. I've created a function that takes an array and a string to search for. If found, it takes note of it's index and then afterwards, moves it to the front of the array and deletes the old one.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.items = ["John","Bob","Tanya","Owen","George"];

    $scope.fixArray = function(array, name){
        angular.forEach(array, function(a){
            if (a == name){
                $scope.index = array.indexOf(a);
            }
        });
        array.unshift(array[$scope.index]);
        array.splice($scope.index + 1, 1);
    };

    $scope.fixArray($scope.items, "Owen");
});
```

Comment: thats a good function, ty. But i have orderBy, so i must flitering array after orderBy

Answer (score 0):

Please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/qcj8lLuUppYzS9ytW0WR?p=preview

Simply do :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items| orderBy">{{item}}</div>
```

Controller

```
var app= angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['John','Bob','Tanya','Owen','George'];
});
```